# What does "Enable Streaming Endpoint" on an Azure Bot Framework Registration do?

Tags: azure, botframework

I was modifying the messaging endpoint URL for one of the Bot Framework bot registrations that I have on Azure, and noticed a new checkbox option that is titled "Enable Streaming Endpoint".  I don't see any documentation yet what this option does, can anyone explain what it is and why you would enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a new feature, related to `Direct Line Speech` channel.

You can see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#enable-the-bot-framework-protocol-streaming-extensions

You can also found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) how to use it in your bot